# displaying a report in report viewer VS 2010

Tags: winforms, reportviewer, report

I am trying to display an already existing .rdl report in report viewer. Is this possible, or does the report have to be created in Report Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a report viewer control and set it to use a Server Report. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104.aspx.

Yes, you definitely can pull up an existing report.